# Wordpress allow + (plus) symbols in slugs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a client with an old website which contains URLs like this

http://www.example.com/this+and+that-as-well-as-this

I need to keep these URLs on the new Wordpress site I am developing. By default Wordpress strips out + symbols leaving me with a URL that doesn't match the old site (I have hundreds of URLs like this).

How can I modify Wordpress to allow this? Open to any suggestions as well as modding core files (although obviously I'd prefer to not do that!)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113323/using-plus-sign-insread-of-space-in-wordpress-url Looks like it can only be done by modifying the core :( It may be possible with `htaccess` however it isn't something I've needed to do before, so don't quote me on it!

Comment: I did see that but doesn't explain what the change would be to make it work. 

Another option is to create my own permalink function that builds the URL I want. Interestingly Wordpress is happy to accept URLs with + in and displays the pages just fine. Its only generating the URLs that are the problem.

My solution so far is to store the old URL in a custom field and check for this with my own permalink building function. But just allowing + symbols would be so much easier!

Comment: could this help? https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18086

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think other popular CMS products (eg Joomla) would allow this either. It's a core design decision for the CMS's slug generation code. It's objectively bad for SEO, so my advice would be to write a htaccess that swaps plus signs for minus signs, and just accept that your URLs are going to change. Users will still be able to get to the right page via the old URLs, so it's not going to break anything.